# No Reverse Match error No idea what is causing

Tags: django, django-urls

I am having some trouble rendering the view for editing profile. I'm not sure what is causing it. 
This is my models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str_(self):
    return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userprofile.save()
```

My views.py

```
class ProfileEditView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    template_name = 'user_profile.html'

    def get_object(self,*args, **kwargs):
        user = get_object_or_404(settings.AUTH_MODEL_USER, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return user.userprofile

    def get_sucess_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse('edit-user')
```

My urls.py is

```
 url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.ProfileEditView.as_view(),name='edit-user')
```

and in my html code I wrote

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'edit-user' %}"> Profile </a>
```

It doesn't give any errors aside from the runtime error of NoReverseMatch with error message

> Reverse for 'edit-user' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/profile/(?P\d+)/$']

Comment: This is because you didn't pass any `pk` to url, post your view which is rending  that html is code

Comment: <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'edit-user' pk=userprofile.id %}"> Profile </a> If I make it like that it's still a noreversematch error but now it gives me  Reverse for 'edit-user' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. How do I properly pass the pk?

Comment: question needs to be clear that what context you are getting in your html, so post the view that is rending this html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line,

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'edit-user' ## missing ## %}"> Profile </a>
```

Add `user.pk` or `userprofile.user.pk` according to where is url is placed in your template.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'edit-user' userprofile.user.pk %}"> Profile </a>
```

or

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'edit-user' user.pk %}"> Profile </a>
```

Choose according to where < a > tag is present in your html.

Comment: Great. You can accept the answer so that others don't click on this question link unnecessarily.